# Setup.cfg With Subpackages containing both Robot and Python

Tags: robotframework, setuptools, python-packaging

I have the following structure in a common library project:

```
root
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── mainpkg
    │   └── common_package
    |   |     └──Robot
    |   |          └── common.robot
    │   └── databases_package
    |   |     └──Python
    |   |     |    └── databases.py
    |   |     └──Robot
    |   |          └── databases.robot
    │   └── Tests
    |   |     └── commonTests.robot
    |   |     └── databaseTests.robot 
    ...
```

I would prefer to organize it into subpackages like this, as this library will grow over time.  For that reason, I also don't want to have to specify the subpackages in setup.cfg, but rather include anything that gets added automatically.  I also want to exclude the Tests - they are for testing any new functionality added to the library, but shouldn't be consumable.

I have the following in my setup.cfg, but when I install in in another package, it's empty.

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
include_package_data = True

[options.packages.find]
where = src
include = *
exclude = Tests
```

I thought that would include everything under the src folder, including subpackages, except Tests.

Comment: Maybe exclude `mainpkg.Tests` or `src/mainpkg/Tests`, I am not sure about the notation.

Comment: @sinoroc - the issue (currently) isn't that the Tests subpackage are showing up; rather, it's that none of the Robot subpackages are showing up.

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` file in each directory below `src`. For example no `src/__init__.py`, but `src/mainpkg/__init__.py`, `src/mainpkg/common_package/__init__.py`,  `src/mainpkg/common_package/Robot/__init__.py`, and so on. Those `__init__.py` files can be completely empty (0 byes), but they have to be there.

Comment: @sinoroc - that works for Python, but doesn't appear to work for the Robot files

Comment: You need to look up how to add "*package data*": https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html